# Form always submitted Jquery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I'm stuck since this morning with [the Jquery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and codeigniter. I have a form with name, email, password... and I check all these fiels with Jquery and then in php.

When the user enters an already used email, a toolbox appears with the error message, BUT the form is still submitted... If I leave an empty email field, it is not submitted.
So I guess when it checks in the database it doesn't do the good action afterwards (it returns false...)

This is the code in my view:

```
    <?php $data_email_signup = array(
        'name'        => 'email_signup',
        'id'          => 'email_signup',
        validate[required,custom[email],ajax[ajaxEmailCall]]'
                        );
            echo form_input($data_email_signup); ?>
...
...

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#form_signup").validationEngine({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

In `jquery.validationEngine-fr.js` I have:

```
"ajaxEmailCall": {
     "url": "/.../ajaxValidateFieldEmail.php",
     "alertTextLoad": "* Please wait",
     "alertText": "* Email already used"
                },
```

In the file `ajaxValidateFieldEmail.php` I have:

```
<?php
$validateValue=$_POST['fieldValue'];
$validateId=$_POST['fieldId'];
$arrayToJs = array();
$arrayToJs[0] = $validateId;
$resultats=$connexion->query("SELECT ...");
$count = $resultats->rowCount();                
if($count == 0){        
    $arrayToJs[1] = true;
    echo json_encode($arrayToJs);
}
else {
    $arrayToJs[1] = false;
    echo json_encode($arrayToJs);
}
?>
```

Firebug returns FALSE and it displays **Email already used** when I enter an already used email but I don't understand why the form is validated anyway.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The code in jquery.validationEngine-fr.js seems to be ok. But when you are doing a full form submit, it has to be treated in a different way.
I use a custom url for validation purposes, because I don't want validation take the same action as the form.
On success I detach the validationengine because in someway it was performing an infinite loop

```
$("#frmAddUser").validationEngine({ajaxFormValidation: true,
      ajaxFormValidationURL: '/users/validate',
      onAjaxFormComplete: function(status, form, json_response_from_server, options)  {
          if (status === true) {
             //validationengine falling into infinite loop
             form.validationEngine('detach');
             form.submit();
          }
      }
 });
```

Because this is a form validation the response from server has to be different to a simple ajax validation, has to be an array of array like this:

```
[[fieldId1, status1, message1], [fieldId2, status2, message2]/*optional*/]
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this while looking for another problem. In the jquery.validationEngine.js

```
_onSubmitEvent: function() {
            var form = $(this);
            var options = form.data('jqv');

            // validate each field (- skip field ajax validation, no necessary since we will perform an ajax form validation)
```

I don't know you if it applies to your problem, or if you solved it, but that comment seems to relate to your problem.

Also, I would make sure your AJAX was returning something useful to your jquery.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onAjaxFormComplete function that is part of the ValidationEngine.  Note in their documentation it states:

> Note that if you use an ajax form validator, the actual result will be delivered asynchronously to the function options.onAjaxFormComplete.

You then have access to 4 pieces of information, however the only ones you're really interested are status and form.

So your initial code to attach to the form becomes:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#form_signup").validationEngine({
            onAjaxFormComplete: function(status,form) {
                if (status === true) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Now the form should only submit if there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You basically are telling it to submit it regardless after the call in here:

```
    **submitHandler: function(form) {

           form.submit();
      }**
```

You might need to use a check with a call back function

```
  function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, json, options)
  {
 if (status === true) form.submit();
  }
```

and then define it as:

```
                         jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                            $("#form_signup").validationEngine({
                                           ajaxFormValidation: true,
                                           ajaxFormValidationMethod: 'post',
                                           onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback 

                                   });
                                          });
```